# How to execute a script written in the response spreadsheet of a google form when we click submit button in the corresponding google form?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I created a **test** **google form**. The form is automatically creating a spreadsheet named **test(response)**. In this spread sheet i wrote the following code

[Script code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIgpL.png)

This code is executing when i click on run button in the app script section.

Currently first i have to open google form enter few response. After that i have to open the script editor of the response spreadsheet, and at last i have to execute the script to get desired result.

I need some help to execute the script code on clicking the submit button in google form, which will make more simpler.

Awaiting for someones reply

Comment: Read the following doc: [Form Submit trigger - information](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1iEB_EwK2rvqHYBRPQsdc4rKODSO1WwyLpirm-edV10E/edit)

Answer (score 0):

Just install a trigger to the response sheet the form is connected to by going to the menu above your script and clicking on the following icon. [image: trigger icon]

You will then specify which function to run and set your event to From spreadsheet as well as On form submit. Click Save.

[image]

This should trigger your script every time a form submission is pulled into the spreadsheet.